# Export COM object or convert to XML

Tags: xml, export, powershell-2.0

I need to export the output of the `Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManagerEX` COM object to an .XML. I have created this script that gets me the source template name and the path for each configured quota in the server.

```bsh
$cuotaInfo = New-Object -com Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManagerex
$cuotaInfo.enumcuotas()| select SourceTemplatesName,Path
```

Output of the command in Windows server 2008:
[image: Output of the command in Windows server 2008]

I am trying to pipe the output with the cmdlets `Export-CliXml` and `Export-Csv` but I am getting this error:

[image]

Any ideas about how to export the output to a manageable file like .xml or .csv?

Comment: The error you posted does not come from exporting the data, but from creating the COM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you posted clearly says that the type `Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManagerex` isn't recognized. Not really surprising when the class name is actually [`Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not `Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManagerex`.

```
PS C:\> $qm = New-Object -COM Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManagerex
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error:
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At line:1 char:7
+ $qm = New-Object -COM Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManagerex
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman...

PS C:\> $qm = New-Object -COM Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManager
PS C:\> $qm.GetType().FullName
System.__ComObject
```